# How to change uploaded file name after save node?

Tags: 8, hooks

Hello and thanks for looking my question.

On Drupal 7 I use this hook [hook_file_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7.x) for change file name.

```
function mymodule_file_presave($file) {
  $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
  $file->filename = $file->uid . $file->timestamp . '.' . $parts['extension'];
}
```

But how to do it on Drupal 8.1.x? Programmatically or module ways or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_entity_presave`?

Description from the DocBlock:

> Act on an entity before it is created or updated.
>   You can get the original entity object from `$entity->original` when it is an update of the entity.

Comment: Yes, thx for answer. But how to write code with this hook, like on my first post? Any example make me understand.

Comment: Try `function yourModule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r(array_keys((array) $entity),1).'</pre>');}` and let me know the result.

Comment: this code return error on white screen

Comment: I've done it for Drupal 9, let me know if you're interested in the answer for v 9